# Shrink a laser spot size

Tags: optics

I have a laser where I can adjust the focal length, however it has a large spot size. I am trying to shrink that down significantly with a microscope objective, how can I go about doing that?

Should I put the laser out of focus, capture the light through the objective, then ensure the objective is at the right height and not out of focus?

Comment: Do you have an objective in mind?  Is it infinity corrected or on old school RMS thread type?